# TabHost: One tab of Activity and second of a View

Tags: android

I want to have a `TabHost` which consists of two tabs: one created from `View` (`R.id.something`) and the second one from `Activity`.

So I do that like this:

```
mTab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTab.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTab.newTabSpec("All");

spec.setContent(R.id.all_tab); // Created from View
        spec.setIndicator("All", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_im_cool));
        mTab.addTab(spec);

Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TasksDone.class);
        spec = mTab.newTabSpec("Done");
        spec.setIndicator("Done", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_im_happy));
        spec.setContent(intent); // Created from Intent
        mTab.addTab(spec);
```

After that the content on the first tab isn't visible, but it's there because I see reaction on my clicks.

But it **appears** if I set the `setContent` of a second tab as a `View` instead of `intent`.

Do you guys know why the content on the first page is invisible?

Comment: you mean that the tab "All" isn't displayed?

Comment: tab "All" is displayed, but it's content is not.

Answer (score 0):

Mh, have you tried `spec.setContent(R.layout.all)`? I assume there should be a layout id, not the id of a view-object.

Comment: Not, there should be namely view object.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was a mistake in xml.